# How to remove ubuntu 12.04 from a dual boot computer with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

sir kindly tell me the steps that i can perfectly remove ubuntu from my computer . dual boot with windows 7 . system configuration is Intel e5200 2.5 Ghz Ram 2GB HDD 500 GB .

Comment: Please follow these links: 1. [uninstall Ubuntu from a dual boot with Windows and fix the boot-loader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) 2. [uninstall Wubi - Ubuntu Installation inside Windows](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/#How_do_I_uninstall_Wubi.3F)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an original installer for Windows 7 for you to be able to recover the Master Boot Record of Windows 7 after removing Ubuntu. It's fairly easy to remove the Ubuntu partition afterwards. [Follow this great guide from makeuseof.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/)